# The term 'Set-AzureADGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: macos, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use a powershell command [Set-AzureADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) from `AzureAD` on Mac. but it kept failing:

> Set-AzureADGroup: The term 'Set-AzureADGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Here are the steps I took:

> Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell

> Set-AzureADGroup

I am using powershell `7.1.5` and my psmodulepath seems right:

> PS /Users/**name> echo $env:PSModulePath
> /Users/**name/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules

If I use:

```
>Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for the **`AzureAD`** module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread) indicate that it ***only runs on Windows***.

While the error message you get when you attempt to import the module on an unsupported platform (such as macOS in your case) unfortunately doesn't *explicitly* say so, it can be *inferred* from its wording: the types in the [`System.Windows.Forms` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms) are available on Windows only.